# Bounding a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, geometric-series

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} < 2 $ by bounding term-to-term with a geometric series.

I thought you'd use $\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{1}{2})^i $ = 2 somehow but the inequality is not inclusive to 2. Also, it's supposed to be done term-to-term.

Could anyone explain how to do it by bounding? Thanks.

Comment: If $$S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{2^i},$$ then $$\frac{1}{2} S= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{2^{i+1}} = \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{j-1}{2^j}.$$ Subtracting the two expressions yields $$S-\frac{1}{2} S = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{1-1/2}  = 1.$$
Which yields $S=2$.

Since the infinite series $S$ equals $2$ and its terms are all positive, its partial sums are all strictly less than $2$. I am not sure why they suggest bounding term by term with a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+...$

$x_0=0, x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$

$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$

$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}$

$\frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-x_n}=\frac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$

So, the ratio between the difference of consecutive terms when $n\ge2$ is always $\le\frac{2}{3}$. The first term in the series starting there is 1/2, so the series is bounded above by $\frac{1/2}{1-2/3}=3/2.$ Add in the first term and we get $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}<2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{i}{2^i} & = & \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^i \dfrac{1}{2^i} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{i = j}^n \dfrac{1}{2^i} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^n \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2^j} - \dfrac{1}{2^{n + 1}}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2}} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^n \left(\dfrac{1}{2^{j - 1}} - \dfrac{1}{2^n}\right) \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} \dfrac{1}{2^j} - \dfrac{n}{2^n} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{2^n}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{2}} - \dfrac{n}{2^n} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle 2 - \dfrac{1}{2^{n - 1}} - \dfrac{n}{2^n} \\[3mm]
& = & \displaystyle 2 - \dfrac{n + 2}{2^n} \\[3mm]
& < & \displaystyle 2
\end{array}$$